# Not Responsive Design (Splash Screen)

Tags: flutter, mobile, responsive, splash-screen

- View

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Constants/color_code.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Screens/SplashNext/splash_next_controller.dart';
import 'package:pet_care/Constants/custom_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
    
class SplashNextView extends GetView<SplashNextController> {
  const SplashNextView({super.key});
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<SplashNextController>(builder: (controller) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 0,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 54.h,),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  controller: controller.onboardingcontroller,
                  itemCount: controller.Onboardinglist.length,
                  onPageChanged: controller.updatebuilddot,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          controller.Onboardinglist[i].photo,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        ),
  
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
  
                        // Build Dot
                        Container(
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: List.generate(
                              controller.Onboardinglist.length,
                              (index) => buildDot(index, context),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
  
                        SizedBox(height: 59.h),
                        Text(controller.Onboardinglist[i].title,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: AppTextStyles.titleTextStyle()),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 16.h,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.w, right: 30.w),
                          child: Text(
                            controller.Onboardinglist[i].description,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: AppTextStyles.subtitleTextStyle(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
    
            // Button
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.w,right: 60.w,bottom: 20.h),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (controller.currentindex ==
                      controller.Onboardinglist.length - 1) {
                    Get.toNamed('/signup');
                  }
                  controller.onboardingcontroller.nextPage(
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      curve: Curves.bounceIn);
                },
                child: CustomButton(
                    button: controller.currentindex ==
                            controller.Onboardinglist.length - 1
                        ? 'Get Started'
                        : 'Next'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }
    
    
  // Build Dot
  Container buildDot(int index, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 10,
      width: controller.currentindex == index ? 25 : 10,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.w),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        color: controller.currentindex == index ? AppColor.font_yellow : AppColor.grey_Border,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- Controller :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SplashNextController extends GetxController {
  int currentindex = 0;
  late PageController onboardingcontroller;

  void updatebuilddot (int index){
    currentindex = index;
    update();
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    onboardingcontroller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    onboardingcontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List Onboardinglist = [
    OnboardingClass('assets/images/splashnext1.png', 'Welcome to Pet Care', 'All types of services for your pet in one place, instantly searchable.'),
    OnboardingClass('assets/images/splashnext2.png', 'Provide experts', 'We interview every specialist before they get to work.'),
    OnboardingClass('assets/images/splashnext3.png', 'Related reviews', 'A review can be left only by a user who used the service.'),
  ];
}

class OnboardingClass {
  final String photo;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  OnboardingClass( this.photo, this.title, this.description);
}
```

Hello Everyone,

I make a splash screen in flutter using getx, which give me below error :

This code gives error in small size devices but works well in large devices, I am fresher so don't have an idea to how make the responsive in all the mobile device. If you have any idea for that then please let me know.

Comment: Share a large and small screenshot, otherwise it's hard to help you like this.